# How to know the status of a two way switch through MCU

Tags: current-measurement, home-automation, nodemcu

My project is this one that I asked earlier (except the fact that I'll be using SPDT switches) [Two way lighting](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/547357/two-way-lighting)

What I'm asking can the MCU detect if the circuit is closed (whether by the physical switch or the MCU triggered relay). I'm thinking some sensor upstream on the appliance/ bulb wire and a ground?
[image]

Comment: Don't ask us to go back and read an old question. Either edit the original question or add all of the needed information to this question. At the very least we need a proper schematic of the circuit as you now envision it.

Comment: I mean I know I could use rectifiers and step-down transformers and attach to MCU but I'd rather not get mains directly to board. Optocouplers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could certainly use an ac current sensor to detect whether or not current is flowing. There are many possible solutions for this, some of which will inherently isolate the detection signal from mains. It's probably time for you to do some additional research into "ac current sensing" and also to think about where all of these pieces of circuitry will be physically located with respect to the physical switch.